# Code Crashes when it tries to take a screenshot

Tags: java, selenium

This is the ligne where my code crashes:

```
File file = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
```

This is the whole code i added into onTestFailure so that i take a screen shot if something goes wrong with my code

```
@Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("TestFailure acces");
            File file = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            File ScreenshotName = new File(".//ScreenShots//test.png");
            System.out.println("Files done");
            try {
                System.out.println("try");
                FileUtils.copyFile(file, ScreenshotName);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.out.println("catch");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Reporter.log("</br><img src='"+ ScreenshotName +"'/>");
            System.out.println("*******Screenshot captured********");
    }
```

I dont have the smallest idea what is the reason for that since when i use the same thing with my test environement it works are there too many times that the test failure is called or what exactly ?

Edit :

The error is :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

When i checked the debugger i saw that my `driver` comes null
My `driver` comme from the class Base

```
package AjouterPanier;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class Base {
    public static WebDriver driver;
}
```

which it self if i understood what i did comes from my main class

```
@Listeners(CustomListener.class)
public class AjoutPanier extends Base {
    WebDriver driver;
    SoftAssert SaAjoutPanier = new SoftAssert();

    String FormatMessageInformatife = "<font color='#73a9d0'></br><i class='fas fa-info-circle'></i>- ";
    String FormatMessageError = "<font color='#bf3d27'></br><i class='fas fa-times-circle'></i>-";
    String FormatMessageSucces = "<font color='#69c158'></br><i class='fas fa-check-circle'></i>-";

    @BeforeTest
    public void LaunchWebsite() {
        // Launch Chrome
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        // Acces Website
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        Reporter.log(FormatMessageSucces + " Chrome is Opened</font>");
    } ....
```

Comment: What does it mean "crashes"? Does it throw an exception and print it out? If yes, show us the whole error!

Comment: @PetrJaneček i did an edit if you wanna check it again

Comment: Well, yes. The `Base` has a static `driver`, but `AjoutPanier` also has a `driver` field. Only the latter gets initiated, the former stays `null`. Rename one of them to make it more clear which one is which. Or remove one. You must always only use the one which you initiate.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was to remove the Base class and make the webdriver in my main class static and extend my main class in the listener.

Main Class :

```
@Listeners(CustomListener.class)
public class AjoutPanier extends Assert {
    public static WebDriver driver;
    SoftAssert SaAjoutPanier = new SoftAssert();
    String FormatMessageInformatife = "<font color='#73a9d0'></br><i class='fas fa-info-circle'></i>- ";
    String FormatMessageError = "<font color='#bf3d27'></br><i class='fas fa-times-circle'></i>- ";
    String FormatMessageSucces = "<font color='#69c158'></br><i class='fas fa-check-circle'></i>-";
        
    @BeforeTest
    public void LaunchWebsite() {
        // Launch Chrome
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        // Acces Website
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        Base b = new Base(driver);
        Reporter.log(FormatMessageSucces + " Chrome is Opened</font>");
    }
//Your code
}
```

Listener is the same as the custome one just instead of calling Base call Main class.

Comment: @Van Please add the code snippet so that it helps others and improves the quality of the answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).